# Обработка слешей в пути к файлам

Tags: python

Вот такой код на питоне получает ошибку:

```py
name = 'C:\Users\Legion\Dropbox\PY\examples\mywc.py'
print(name)
```

ошибка:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Я конечно могу написать так: `r'C:\Users\Legion\Dropbox\PY\examples\mywc.py'` и ошибка исчезнет. Но я думал, что как-то можно потом обработать строку в name перед принт, например:
`name2 = r'{}'.format(name)`, однако, все такие манипуляции приводят к такой же ошибке.

Получается, строка, записанная  в name, уже безвозвратно "испорчена" попыткой преобразования?

Интересно, решилась бы проблема, если бы просто для путей в windows или для управляющих символов использовались бы отличные символы от "`\`"? Зачем так придумано, чтобы слеш использовался и в пути windows, и одновременно для управляющих символов?

Comment: Вы можете спокойно писать в путях прямой слеш `/` вместо обратного и в большинстве случаев это будет работать нормально.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать pathlib

```
from pathlib import Path
path0 = Path('C:/Users/Legion/Dropbox/PY/examples/mywc.py')
path1 = Path('C:\\Users\\Legion\\Dropbox\\PY\\examples\\mywc.py')
path3 = Path(r'C:\Users\Legion\Dropbox\PY\examples\mywc.py')
print(path0.name)
print(path1.name)
print(path3.name)
print(f' {path0}\n {path1} \n {path3}')
```

---

```
mywc.py
mywc.py
mywc.py
C:\Users\Legion\Dropbox\PY\examples\mywc.py
C:\Users\Legion\Dropbox\PY\examples\mywc.py 
C:\Users\Legion\Dropbox\PY\examples\mywc.py
```

Comment: path0 = Path('C:/Users/Legion/Dropbox/PY/examples/mywc.py')
path1 = Path('C:\\Users\\Legion\\Dropbox\\PY\\examples\\mywc.py')
path3 = Path(r'C:\Users\Legion\Dropbox\PY\examples\mywc.py')

Изначально правильные форматы путей. Проблему не решает это.
Пользователь передает путь как C:\Users\Legion\Dropbox\PY\examples\mywc.py , и, предположим, не хочет менять в нем слеши или ставить r. (ему об этом может быть даже неизвестно). 
Аргумент функции получает такой путь и файл открыть невозможно.

Я так подозреваю, что ничего сделать нельзя, кроме как сразу передавать путь в правильном формате?

Comment: @Demmiat: *«Пользователь передает путь как C:\Users\Legion\Dropbox\PY\examples\mywc.py»* - где это в вашем вопросе??? (Нужно его отредактировать, добавить это прямо в вопрос.) ― Когда **пользователь** передал такой путь, **точно таким** (значит, **правильным**) он будет и в соответствующей переменной. *Ни каких букв `r`, двойных слешов или замен за нормальные слеши не нужно.*

Comment: @Demmiat: См. [Что такое «Ошибка молотка»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/233990)

Comment: Прочитайте пожалуйста мой вопрос в посте ещё раз, не спеша, тогда ни о каких молотках разговора не будет))) Вся остальная философия от меня, это уже доп рассуждения, и ими необязательно забивать изначальный простой вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Из вашего вопроса:

> Получается, строка, записанная в name, уже безвозвратно "испорчена" попыткой преобразования?

Нет. Она не испорчена, она **не существует**, потому что это просто *неправильная форма для записи строкового литерала.*

Ошибка здесь:

```
name = 'C:\Users\Legion\Dropbox\PY\examples\mywc.py'
          ↑↑
```

`\U` это начало *экранированной постепенности 8 шестнадцатеричных цифр для введения символа в форме Юникод,* например `\U0000042f` для буквы `Я`.

Значит, **после символа `\U` ожидается 8 шестнадцатеричных цифр**, что в вашем случае не так — символ `s` после `\U` (в части `\Users`) не является такой цифрой.

---

Как это исправить?

Существует несколько возможностей — выберите любую из них:

1. Вместо **обратных** слешов (`\`) используйте **нормальные** (`/`) - да, это возможно даже в Windows:

   ```
   name = 'C:/Users/Legion/Dropbox/PY/examples/mywc.py'
   ```
2. Вместо **одного** обратного слеша (`\`) используйте всегда **пару** (`\\`) - это экранированная постепенность для одного слеша:

   ```
   name = 'C:\\Users\\Legion\\Dropbox\\PY\\examples\\mywc.py'
   ```
3. **Непосредственно перед строку включите символ `r` или `R`** (от английского слова **row**, сырой), чтобы все символы интерпретировались буквально, а не как экранированные последовательности:

   ```
   name = r'C:\Users\Legion\Dropbox\PY\examples\mywc.py'
   ```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, я это понимаю. Вопрос и проблема не в том, чтобы изменить правильным образом строковый литерал 3-я способами описанными, а в том, возможно ли это сделать после того, как "неправильная" строка со слешами передана в функцию или записана в переменную (name = 'C:\Users\Legion\Dropbox\PY\examples\mywc.py')???  Я так подозреваю, что нет.

Между 
name = 'C:\Users\Legion\Dropbox\PY\examples\mywc.py'
и
print(name)
нужно привести name в соответствие.

Comment: @Demmiat, для вашего совета (в комментарии к другому ответу) я прочитал ваш вопрос еще раз, не спеша. В команде `name = 'C:\Users\Legion\Dropbox\PY\examples\mywc.py'`, возникает ошибка, в этом мы согласимся. После ней вы можете в **непосредственном интерпретаторе** (REPL) Питона написать правильную команду (мы тоже согласимся в том, как она должна выглядеть) и она правильно выполнится — никакой ошибки (у меня) после ней нет. Значит, **я не могу воспроизвести вашу ошибку**. (Я предполагаю, что вы не запускаете **файл** с правильной командой после неправильной.)

Comment: Да, прошу прощения за невнимательность. Я думал ошибка на этапе print(name) или open(name), а она вообще сразу при присваивании.

Comment: @Demmiat, все в порядке. Между прочим, точное место ошибки находилось все время в моем ответе, почти в начале, после слов **«Ошибка здесь:»** - и затем команда присваивания. :-)